# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

I am an obvious beginner of laravel and I am having a problem about this :
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

I don't know on what seems to be the problem.. Whenever I hit the register button, That error would show up. What would be the probable cause for this error?

AdminController.php:

```
<?php

class AdminController extends Basecontroller{

    public function index()
    {   
        return View::make('content.index');
    } 

    public function registration()
    {
        return View::make('content.registration');
    }

    public function registrationSave()
    {
        $input= Input::all();
        $rules = array('username'=>'required|unique:admin', 'name'=>'required|unique:admin', 'password'=>'required');
        $validate = Validator::make($input,$rules);
        if($validate->passes())
        {
            $password = $input['password'];
            $password = Hash::make($password);

            $user= new User();
            $user->username=$input['username'];
            $user->name=$input['name'];
            $user->password=$password;
            $user->save();

            return Redirect::to('registration');

        }
    }

}
```

routes.php:

```
    Route::get('/','AdminController@index');

// Admin Registration
Route::get('admin/registration','AdminController@registration');
Route::post('admin/registration','AdminController@registrationSave');
```

registration.blade.php:

```
   @extends('layouts.master')
   @section('content')
     {{ Form::open(['url'=>'admin/registrationSave']) }}
          <div>
          {{ Form::label('name','Name: ') }} 
          {{ Form::text('name','',['placeholder'=>'Name']) }}          
          </div>
          <div>      
          {{ Form::label('username','Username: ') }} 
          {{ Form::text('username','',['placeholder'=>'Username']) }}
          </div>
          <div>
          {{ Form::label('password','Password: ') }} 
          {{ Form::password('password','',['placeholder'=>'Password']) }}          
          </div>

          <div>
          {{ Form::submit('Register') }}
          </div>
       {{ Form::close() }}
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ Form::open(['url'=>'admin/registrationSave']) }}
```

It looks like you're trying to point the URL to the method name of the controller, rather than the URL of the route itself.  The get/post routes share the same actual URL, so change that line to this:

```
{{ Form::open(['url'=>'/admin/registration']) }}
```

Comment: Sir, one more thing. Another error occurs, QLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table.. What could have I possibly done wrong?

Comment: You either a) don't have a user table migration created, or b) you have one but you just haven't run it yet.  See [this documentation page](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations) for more info on migrations or feel free to [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)!.